# Querdsl: Convert SQL with join into Querdsl JPA syntax

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to convert this snippet of SQL into a QueryDSL JPA query:

```
SELECT tp.*
FROM task_protocol tp
JOIN (
    SELECT task_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM task_protocol
    -- WHERE ...
    GROUP BY task_id
) AS max_tuple
ON tp.id = max_tuple.max_id
-- ...;
```

What I have come up so far, which does not compile and I'm not sure I'm heading in the right direction:

```
final NumberPath<Long> id = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "id");
final NumberPath<Long> taskId = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "taskId");

final JPQLQuery<Tuple> maxTuple = //
  JPAExpressions.select(protocol.taskId.as(taskId), protocol.id.max().as(id)) //
        .from(protocol) //
        // .where(...) //
        .groupBy(protocol.taskId);
 
new JPAQuery<Protocol>(entityManager).from(protocol) //
  .join(maxTuple) // <- this does not compile
  .on(protocol.id.eq(id))
  // ...
  .fetch();
```